# Unable to view badge achievement within the app

Tags: support, badges, android-app, achievements-dialog

I was just awarded a badge, proceeded to click it on the achievements section, and selected the option to open within the app:

> [image]
>
> [image]

But it did not display the outcome within the app, and redirected me to my Browser instead:

> [image]

I wonder what could have caused this behavior? This was confusing to me because *the option to open within app was given* and I expected it to display the result in the app.

Any clues here? I suppose this could be by-design, but in that case shouldn't the option to open in app be removed?

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: HUAWEI
- Device Model: HUAWEI VNS-L23
- OS Version: 6.0 (C45B130)

---

*Update:* Just tried again (the next day) and still same result. I have no default Browser selected in my phone.

Also, if I let the redirection to take place it takes me to: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/73791/darkcygnus?tag=badges , which I happened to noticed is the same as https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/73791/darkcygnus?tab=topactivity

Comment: Is your default action(open with browser or app) set? Can you try to reproduce this and check if it continues? It sometimes happens to me when the network is not stable.

Comment: Yes, it happens every time I click it. I don't have a default Browser, so every time it asks me where to open (same case when clicking SE questions on my browser, it asks me if I want on app or not)

Comment: Yep, just did it again now and same thing

Comment: This links to the Help Center as far as I can tell, and since the android app has no Help Center, it shows that message.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If I let the redirection to my Browser to happen, it takes me to: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/73791/darkcygnus?tag=badges

Comment: @DarkCygnus oh. Well, the app also doesn't have a real user profile.